# latex command to genenerate output similar to this website

Tags: tex4ht, html, htlatex

How can I generate latex with the following format in latex? I know about `tex4ht` and I know about `latex4html` but couldn't get similar output.

[Source Website is here](http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/c++std/cd2/intro.html#intro) and a snapshot from the page is given below

[image]

Sample Tex File (Notice the tables in the above link)

```
\documentclass[ebook,10pt,oneside,openany,final]{memoir}

\usepackage[american]
           {babel}        % needed for iso dates
\usepackage[iso,american]
           {isodate}      % use iso format for dates
\usepackage[final]
           {listings}     % code listings


\setcounter{totalnumber}{10}

% Base definitions for tables
\newenvironment{TableBase}
{
 \renewcommand{\tcode}[1]{{\CodeStylex{##1}}}
 \newcommand{\topline}{}
 \newcommand{\capsep}{}
 \newcommand{\rowsep}{}
 \newcommand{\bottomline}{}

%% vertical alignment
 \newcommand{\rb}[1]{\raisebox{1.5ex}[0pt]{##1}}    % move argument up half a row

%% header helpers
 \newcommand{\hdstyle}[1]{\textbf{##1}}             % set header style
 \newcommand{\Head}[3]{\multicolumn{##1}{##2}{\hdstyle{##3}}}   % add title spanning multiple columns
 \newcommand{\lhdrx}[2]{\Head{##1}{|c}{##2}}        % set header for left column spanning #1 columns
 \newcommand{\chdrx}[2]{\Head{##1}{c}{##2}}         % set header for center column spanning #1 columns
 \newcommand{\rhdrx}[2]{\Head{##1}{c|}{##2}}        % set header for right column spanning #1 columns
 \newcommand{\ohdrx}[2]{\Head{##1}{|c|}{##2}}       % set header for only column spanning #1 columns
 \newcommand{\lhdr}[1]{\lhdrx{1}{##1}}              % set header for single left column
 \newcommand{\chdr}[1]{\chdrx{1}{##1}}              % set header for single center column
 \newcommand{\rhdr}[1]{\rhdrx{1}{##1}}              % set header for single right column
 \newcommand{\ohdr}[1]{\ohdrx{1}{##1}}
 \newcommand{\br}{\hfill\break}                     % force newline within table entry

%% column styles
 \newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\\=\tabularnewline}p{##1}}  % word-wrapped ragged-right
                                                                    % column, width specified by #1
 % \newcolumntype{m}[1]{>{\CodeStyle}l{##1}}              % variable width column, all entries in CodeStyle
 \newcolumntype{m}[1]{l{##1}}                           % variable width column, all entries in CodeStyle
}
{
}

% General Usage: TITLE is the title of the table, XREF is the
% cross-reference for the table. LAYOUT is a sequence of column
% type specifiers (e.g. cp{1.0}c), without '|' for the left edge
% or right edge.

% usage: \begin{floattablebase}{TITLE}{XREF}{COLUMNS}{PLACEMENT}
% produces floating table, location determined within limits
% by LaTeX.
\newenvironment{floattablebase}[4]
{
 \begin{TableBase}
 \begin{table}[#4]
 \caption{\label{#2}#1}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|#3|}
}
{
 \bottomline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
 \end{table}
 \end{TableBase}
}

% usage: \begin{floattable}{TITLE}{XREF}{COLUMNS}
% produces floating table, location determined within limits
% by LaTeX.
\newenvironment{floattable}[3]
{
 \begin{floattablebase}{#1}{#2}{#3}{htbp}
}
{
 \end{floattablebase}
}


\newcommand{\CodeStylex}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\tcode}[1]{\CodeStylex{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{floattable}
{Potential \tcode{setlocale} data races}
{tab:setlocale.data.races}
{lllll}
\topline

\tcode{fprintf}     &
\tcode{isprint}     &
\tcode{iswdigit}    &
\tcode{localeconv}  &
\tcode{tolower}     \\

\end{floattable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which aspect of that site is the one you want? The "plain text" formatting? The fixed-width font? The underlines in the titles? The  bracketed [labels] at the sections? Why use latex if the result is not intended for printing? It looks as if nroff or texinfo, or markdown were better alternatives.

Comment: actually all of it :).

Comment: Looking at the source code of those pages, you can discover that all the content is basically pre-formatted and included in a big `<pre>` tag. It looks as if it was written directly in plain text, or processed with `nroff`. I can't see any relationship with LaTeX. Perhaps you can take some ideas from http://www.rfc-editor.org/formatting.html

Comment: You can get an nroff editor http://aaa-sec.com/nroffedit/. LaTeX unfortunately cannot be used for badly formatted text, except under duress:)

Comment: unfortunately i have tex files.. so i need something that can convert stuff..

Comment: @RamneekHanda could you please post sample TeX file? I think what you want can be done with tex4ht and some css, but we need some playground for testing

Comment: @RamneekHanda well and what about sections and enumerated items? Are they created using standard macros?

Comment: @michal.h21 I have attached the git hub for sources.. you can look at the style files.. apologies for being a total dope with tex.. i am learning it now.. thanks for all the help again. https://github.com/ramneek-handa/draft/tree/master/source

Comment: @RamneekHanda no need to apologise, I will look at the files later

Comment: @michal.h21 much thanks! the tables related stuff is in a separate tex file. I have commented out all the tables so that i can use htlatex at the moment. what i would like to do is fix the tables file and then uncomment the tables usage in the main tex files. let me know if you have any questions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code relates to [project](https://github.com/ramneek-handa/draft/tree/master/source) which OP mentioned in the comments.

I would convert files with macro definitions to `sty` files. So rename files `macros.tex`, `layout.tex`, etc. to `macros.sty` etc. In your main file, call them then with `\usepackage`. Thanks of that, you can then provide configuration files for `tex4ht`.

You should rewrite some macros, to be easier for modification. for example. you have in `macros.tex` this macro:

```
\def\Sec#1[#2]#3{{%
\ifcase#1\let\s=\chapter
      \or\let\s=\section
      \or\let\s=\subsection
      \or\let\s=\subsubsection
      \or\let\s=\paragraph
      \or\let\s=\subparagraph
      \fi%
\s[#3]{#3\hfill[#2]}\label{#2}}}
```

As with `tex4ht` you will need to insert there some html tags, it would be better to modify it little bit:

```
\def\Sec#1[#2]#3{{%
\ifcase#1\let\s=\chapter
      \or\let\s=\section
      \or\let\s=\subsection
      \or\let\s=\subsubsection
      \or\let\s=\paragraph
      \or\let\s=\subparagraph
      \fi%
      \s[#3]{\SecParts{#3}{#2}}\edef\@currentlabel{_#2_}\label{#2}}}


\newcommand\SecParts[2]{#1\hfill[#2]}
```

Now you need only to redefine `\SecParts` macro in your `tex4ht` config file to insert some html tags. `\edef\@currentlabel{_#2_}` is here because you wanted cross-references with labels and underscores instead of section numbers.

I created configuration file `macros.4ht`, where I put some redefinitions:

```
% hooks definitions 

\NewConfigure{SecParts}{3}
\renewcommand\SecParts[2]{\a:SecParts#1\b:SecParts#2\c:SecParts}

\NewConfigure{Pnum}{2}
\def\pnum{\addtocounter{Paras}{1}\noindent\a:Pnum\arabic{Paras}\b:Pnum}

\Configure{SecParts}{}{\HCode{<span class="SecLabel">[}}{\HCode{]</span>}}
\Configure{Pnum}{\HCode{<span class="pnum">}}{\HCode{</span>}}

\Css{
body{
  width:60em;
  margin-left:4em;
  font-family:monospace;
}}

\Css{
 h1, h2, h3{font-size:1em;font-weight:normal;}
}
\Css{h2 br{display:none}}
\Css{
.titlemark{display:inline-block;margin-right:.5em;margin-left:0;}
}
\Css{
 p{
     text-align:justify;
     -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
     hyphens: auto;
}    
}
\Css{.pnum{
display:block; width: 2em; margin-left:-2em; float:left;
}}
\Css{.SecLabel{
  display:block;
  float:right;
}
}
\Hinput{macros.sty}
```

With `\NewConfigure` commands I created configurable hooks, then with `\renewcommand` I redefined commands where I need to put these hooks. I think you have many macros, where you should use similar redefinitions for inserting html tags, so you can do that this way.

And major part of this file are css definitions which affects appearance.

[image]

Comment: thanks.. will have a look at it later tonight and accept the answer.. i have really made progress thanks to your knowledge :)..

Comment: a quick question though.. is it the complete solution or will i have to go about learning what you have done and replicate it for other sty files?

Comment: @RamneekHanda it is complete solution for general layout, I think. But you will probably want and need to adapt some document markup macros, to be able to assign html tags for their content and to be able to apply CSS styling

Comment: Perfect.. though i still get this warning and if i keep pressing ctrl-D.. it eventually does create the document in the form expected... can you help me solve this warning - (./utilities.aux
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.811 ...LiNK{x1-669000_time.traits.is_fp_}{750}}}

Comment: @RamneekHanda I don't know what is the problem, maybe there is some problem with underscore? I  know that tex4ht is playing with underscore catcodes

Comment: anyways :).. thanks a lot.. i am going to have some more issues that i am going to post questions for later..